# How do I store then retrieve Python-native data structures into and from a file?

Tags: python, file, pickle

I am reading an XML file and reorganizing the desired data into Python data structures (lists, tuples, etc.)

For example, one of my XML parser modules produces the following data:

```
# data_miner.py
animals = ['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse']
population = [150, 200, 50, 30]
```

Then I have a plotter module that roughly says, e.g.:

```
# plotter.py
from data_miner import animals, population

plot(animals, population)
```

Using this method, I have to parse the XML file every time I do a plot. I'm still testing other aspects of my program and the XML file doesn't change as frequently for now. Avoiding the parse stage would dramatically improve my testing time.

**This is my desired result:**
In between `data_miner.py` and `plotter.py`, I want a file that contains `animals` and `population` such that they can be accessed by `plotter.py` natively (e.g. no change in plotting code), without having to run `data_miner.py` every time. If possible, it shouldn't be in `csv` or any ASCII format, just a natively-accessible format. `plotter.py` should now look roughly like:

```
# plotter.py

# This line may not necessarily be a one-liner.
from data_file import animals, population

# But I want this portion to stay the same
plot(animals, population)
```

**Analogy:**
This is roughly equivalent to MATLAB's `save` command that saves the active workspace's variables into a `.mat` file. I'm looking for something similar to the `.mat` file for Python.

**Recent experience:**
I have seen `pickle` and `cpickle`, but I'm not sure how to get it to work. If that is the right tool to use, example code would be very helpful. There may also be other tools that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pickle` module, or its faster equivalent `cPickle`, should serve your needs well.

Specifically:

```
# data_miner.py
import pickle

animals = ['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse']
population = [150, 200, 50, 30]

with open('data_miner.pik', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump([animals, population], f, -1)
```

and

```
# plotter.py
import pickle

with open('data_miner.pik', 'rb') as f:
    animals, population = pickle.load(f)

print animals, population
```

Here, I've made `data_miner.py` quite explicit regarding what needs to be saved (always an excellent idea to be very explicit unless you have extremely specific reasons to do otherwise).  Some things (such as modules and open files) cannot be pickled anyway, so a simple pickling of `globals()` would not work.

If you absolutely must, you *could* make a copy of `globals()` while removing all objects whose types make them unsuitable for saving; or, perhaps better, religiously use a leading `_` in every name you **don't** want to save (so `import pickle as _pickle`, `with open ... as _f`, and so forth) and exclude from the copy of `globals()` all names with a leading underscore == with such an approach, the `pickle.load` would retrieve a `dict`, then the variables of interest would be extracted from it by indexing.  However, I would strongly recommend the simple alternative of saving a `list` (or `dict`, if you want;-) with the *specific* values that are actually of interest, rather than taking a "wholesale" approach.

Comment: +1 for the extra info about `globals()`. Something new for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Pickling is good if you have Python-specific objects to save. If they're just generic data in some basic container type then [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) is fine.

```
>>> json.dumps(['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse'])
'["Chicken", "Sheep", "Cattle", "Horse"]'
>>> json.dump(['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse'], sys.stdout) ; print
["Chicken", "Sheep", "Cattle", "Horse"]
>>> json.loads('["Chicken", "Sheep", "Cattle", "Horse"]')
[u'Chicken', u'Sheep', u'Cattle', u'Horse']
```

Answer (score 1):

`pickle` was designed for this.  Use `pickle.dump` to write an object to a file and `pickle.load` to read it back.

```
>>> data
{'animals': ['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse'], 'population': [150, 200, 50, 30]}
>>> f = open('spam.p', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(data, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('spam.p', 'rb')
>>> pickle.load(f)
{'animals': ['Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Cattle', 'Horse'], 'population': [150, 200, 50, 30]}
```

Comment: I see that you converted `data` into another structure, which I would like to avoid, since my data is already structured in rather complicated nested lists. Is there a way to make `data_miner.py` do something at the end like `save all variables within my scope` and `store it to some binary file`?

Comment: You can use `locals()` to get a `dict` containing all the local variables.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, pickle is usually used here. Keep in mind that not everything is serializable (i.e. files, sockets, database connections).

With simple data structures you can also chose json or yaml. The latter is actually pretty readable and editable.

Comment: Incidentally, you can also store complex data structures in JSON and YAML.

Comment: But not arbitrary objects (except for non-serializable in general) with references (possibly circular), and so on. Right?