# Does Python have a native output file format?

Tags: python, file-format

Does Python have a native output file format?  For example, SAS has native data sets (*.sas7bdat files).  Does Python have an equivalent?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589615/how-do-i-store-then-retrieve-python-native-data-structures-into-and-from-a-file

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html maybe, but you'd likely be better asking about a concrete problem you're trying to solve, this seems like an XY problem.